# SQL Server : escape punctuation in string

Tags: string, csv, sql-server-2012, escaping, email-attachments

I am exporting data from a SQL Server table to a `.csv` file, and then I use `sp_send_email` to email the file with data.

My problem is with this value:

```
Cantata Number 212 "Peasants Cantata", BWV 212
```

The value gets split into two columns in the `.csv` file that gets emailed. This value should be only in one column.

Some titles might contain a comma, which needs to be left in the string for those instances.

For example:

```
Cantata Number 212 Peasants Cantata"     BWV 212"
```

I tried this method, but is not working:

**Note**: This `SELECT` statement resides inside a view `vw_WeeklyReport`

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
    '"' + [p].[Title] + '"' [Title]
FROM
    table
```

The code that exports the data and emails the `.csv` file:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(8000);

    -- Create the query, concatenating the column name as an alias
    SET @Qry = 'SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT Title FROM [vw_WeeklyReport] SET NOCOUNT OFF';

    -- Send the e-mail with the query results in attachment.
    EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] 
                @profile_name = 'default',
                @recipients = '6lack@email.com',
                @subject = 'Weekly Report',
                @body = 'An attachment has been included in this email.',
                @query_attachment_filename = 'WeeklyRep.csv',
                @query = @qry,
                @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
                @query_result_separator = ',',
                @query_result_width = 32767,
                @query_result_no_padding = 1;
END;
```

Comment: If it's acceptable to strip out the commas, you should look into using `replace` within SQL to do exactly that.

Comment: Some values will contain commas and it is necessary to leave the commas in the string.

Comment: The other option would be to rework the export to use a different delimiter besides a comma, though that's probably outside of the scope of a single SO question.

Comment: do you know what other delimiters can be used? I tried semicolon, but when I used it, then I get all the data in only one column of the.csv file

Comment: You can use any delimiter you want.  Really all a csv is, is a formatted text document.  You will likely need to alter whatever is parsing the csv currently, like I said though that's beyond the scope of a single SO question.

Answer (score 1):

When there are comma's (or separators) in the field, that field should be enclosed with double quotes, and any double quotes within have to be escaped with another double quote:

```
"Cantata Number 212 ""Peasants Cantata"", BWV 212"
```

Once double quotes are used around fields, all fields containing double quotes should also be quoted and inside quotes escaped as well.

Maybe you could look for an option to export to csv using quoted fields.

Removing all the comma's could also be an option, but then you lose some information.

On the other hand, if there is only one column (as in your SELECT statement) there is no need at all to use csv. A plain text file can be used instead.

Comment: There are other columns, I just included the one that is giving me trouble

Comment: @the_lone_note Ok, then you'll have to format the field as shown above (or maybe use an export option for that, if one exists). Or replace `"` with `""` in your field.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query in the stored proc to something like this:

```
SET @Qry = 'SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT replace(Title, ',', '') as Title FROM [vw_WeeklyReport] SET NOCOUNT OFF';
```

Note this is untested, but should give you what you're looking for.  This is under the presumption that stripping out commas is acceptable, as was indicated in the initial post.  If the commas need to remain intact, the answer isn't quite as simple.